# Datetimepicker error in React JS code : error Uncaught TypeError: Cal.GetMonDays is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a requirement to have the date and time format as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS in my react JS calender tag. But i dont find a suitable library for it.

I used a similar library in JQuery called datetimepicker_css.js and it worked fine. But when i use it in react js code, it throws an error Uncaught TypeError: Cal.GetMonDays is not a function. I am not sure why. If anyone has any inputs on this, it would be highly appreciated.

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

2016-03-10 10:42:22

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the error you're getting with the jQuery plugin.

If its a library you're looking for, take a look at http://momentjs.com/

If you're using a build system, to implement it with react, install it as a node package, and in the file you need it just require it using the commonjs pattern.

```
var moment = require('moment');
```

Then in the JSX you should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Moment js.

```
moment().format('YYYY[-]MM[-]DD, h:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not want to use any library. Writing a utility method can be useful

```
dateToString(date){

    let d = new Date(date);
    let month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1);
    let day = '' + d.getDate();
    let year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    let formattedDate = [year, month, day].join('-');

    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let suffix = (hours >= 12)? 'PM' : 'AM';
    let hh = ((hours + 11) % 12 + 1);
    let mm = (minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes;
    let formattedTime = hh + ":" + mm + " " + suffix;
    return formattedDate +" "+ formattedTime;
}
```